# Django - ServiceWorker, Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request failed

Tags: javascript, python, django, ecmascript-6, progressive-web-apps

I want to use ServiceWorker of javascript to cache an HTML file for offline view. But problem is I have a django application. and I don't know how can I specify my template files in service-worker.js.

I specified a URL for service-worker.js in my urls.py like this -
`path('service-worker.js', (TemplateView.as_view(template_name="menu/service-worker.js", content_type='application/javascript', )), name='service-worker.js')`

this is my index.html template file -

```
     <script>
        if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      let registration;
    
      const registerServiceWorker = async () => {
        registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("{% url 'service-worker.js' %}");
      };
    
      registerServiceWorker();
    }
    </script>
```

everything working great so far.

this is my service-worker.js

```
const cacheName = 'my-cache';

const filesToCache = [
  "/index.html",
];

self.addEventListener('activate', e => self.clients.claim());

self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName)
    .then(cache => cache.addAll(filesToCache))
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request)
    .then(response => response ? response : fetch(e.request))
  )
});
```

I'm getting this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request failed` and I know this is because `index.html` file is not found and returning 404 error. but I don't have any idea how should I specify the template file here. can anyone please help me with how should I import template files in service-worker. or I may have some totally different problem. Thank you!